# Particles don't follow curve

Tags: particles, physics, bezier-curves, nurbs-surface

I'm trying to create a **traffic** simulation with the **particle system**. I want to create a lot of cars that walk **along a path**...I'm just following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWEwxtu9gGc&t=1s&fbclid=IwAR0TmMM3HDO3S-scNSGg4YO4cZsXTCHtFLcydgbTEPvBXrnFEix0S5OGQKQ) :

The problem is that when I setup the **force field type** to **curve guide**,the particles don't follow the **nurbspath**,but in the tutorial they do. Can u tell me why ?

[image: 1] 
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

[You can get the Blender file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pTC0Pv6URH-0S2ZVHQkZWhIMrSp5iC4C)

Comment: Make sure you have enabled "Path Animation" in Curve tab settings. Maybe also check "Follow" option

Comment: done,but still does not work. Do u want to look inside the blender file ? I have attached on the question above.

Answer (score 3):

There is couple of thing you should do.

**1. Switch direction of your path**

Enter *Edit mode* and in *N-panel* find *Curve Display* -> *Normals*, make it bigger to see actual direction of the curve. You need to keep direction "from the particle system". So select every vertex and hit <kbd>W</kbd> -> *Switch Direction*

**2. Participant elements of Particle Physics have to be on the same layer**

Right now your *Particle System* and *Curve guide force* are placed on different layers. Move the *Curve* on the same layer where *Particle System* is.

**3. Check "Path Animation" option in curve's settings**

*Curve guide force* will not be working without enabling this thing

[image]